# Are "comma" names in IE languages somehow related with yarn?

Tags: proto-indo-european, indo-european

The Russian name of "comma" is "запятая zapjatája" which is cognate to english "to spin"(a yarn)
The Russian name of "full stop" is "точка tóčka" which is cognate to "ткать tkatʹ" (to weave)
The question is whether the form of a comma is somehow related with the procce of spinning a yarn?
Are "comma" names in other languages somehow related with yarn?
[image: [![enter image description here][1]][1]]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

No connection with yarn even in Russian: *запятая* 'comma' is derived from *запинаться* 'to stammer, to stutter' in the meaning of making a pause, and *точка* 'period' is from *тыкать* 'to poke, to pierce' describing the manner it is written. Mind that the shape of the comma in your image is taken from a modern typeface, other typefaces have it different. As for the [origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma#History) of the classic shape of the comma used today, it is descended from `/`, a diagonal slash used in the 13th-17th centuries to represent a pause.

The fact that some meanings of the roots used in Russian words for 'comma' and 'period' are connected with weaving is a mere coincidence.

Comment: As I previously said запинаться is cognate to "spin". As I know people spin yarn.

Comment: "тыкать " is from "тъкать" but not vice versa, so "точка" is from "тъкать". ы is a elongated version of ъ. moreover "запинаться" is from "запятая" more precisely from "запяти" but not vice versa

Comment: The root of "запятая" doesn't mean "to stammer" but "to stretch" see "распятый"  https://ksana-k.ru/dict/stsl/sl0576.png

Comment: @Peter - Note: compare _распять_ -  _распинать_ - _распинаться_ with _запять_ -  _запинать_ - _запинаться_. The Russian word for 'comma' is as much connected with yarn making as the Russian word for 'to crucify' does. The words are really cognates, but there's no connection between the shape of the comma and spinning yarn. The root of "запятая" doesn't mean "to stammer" but the word _запинаться_ from which "запятая" is derived does mean "to stammer".

Comment: As I previously said "запинаться"  is derived from verb "запяти" past participle "запятая" but not vice versa because "я" is from "en", "e" before sonoric r, l, n turn into "ь" compare дьрати, бьрати and only then "ь" elongates into "и". In total en > ьн > ин

Comment: so the real meaning of "запятая" past particaple of "запяти" to stretch is "stretched".

Comment: @Peter - Yes, stretching the time, that is making a pause, but there is no connection with yarn.